# How to align text with the bottom of an XSL-FO block?

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I am writing an XSLT script, that transforms an XML input document to an XSL-FO intermediate document, which get transformed into a PDF output document.

My `fo:simple-page-master` exists out of three parts, a page header, body, and footer.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="a4-portrait"
        page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm"
        margin-top="0mm" margin-right="12mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-left="12mm">
        <fo:region-body region-name="page-body" margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="page-header" extent="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="page-footer" extent="20mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="a4-landscape"
        page-width="297mm" page-height="210mm"
        margin-top="0mm" margin-right="12mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-left="12mm">
        <fo:region-body region-name="page-body" margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="page-header" extent="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="page-footer" extent="20mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```

Here is a simple *hello world* page:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="a4-portrait">
    <!-- Page header -->
    <fo:static-content flow-name="page-header">
        <fo:block vertical-align="text-bottom">Some headline in the page header</fo:block>
        <fo:block vertical-align="text-bottom" border-bottom="0.25pt solid black"></fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <!-- Page footer -->
    <fo:static-content flow-name="page-footer">
        <fo:block border-top="0.25pt solid black"></fo:block>
        <fo:block>Page <fo:page-number/></fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>

    <!-- Page body -->
    <fo:flow flow-name="page-body">
        <fo:block>Hello World!</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

As you can see, I already tried the `vertical-align="text-bottom"` approach. Unfortunately, the `fo:block`-elements did not align to the bottom of the superordinate element.

**How to write the XSLT in order to have the `page-header` writes the text from bottom to top, instead of top-to-bottom?**

XSLT 2.0, XPath 2.0, Apache FOP, Saxon-HE 9.8

Comment: I see you have your answer, but it is totally unclear how that "writes the text from bottom to top, instead of top-to-bottom?" You must mean one block of text, not that the blocks stack up from bottom to top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display-align="after"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#display-align).

`display-align` applies to `fo:region-before` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-before) as well as to the other regions, `fo:block-container`, `fo:external-graphic`, `fo:instream-foreign-object`, `fo:inline-container`, and `fo:table-cell`.

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="a4-portrait"
        page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm"
        margin-top="0mm" margin-right="12mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-left="12mm">
        <fo:region-body region-name="page-body" margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="page-header" extent="20mm" display-align="after"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="page-footer" extent="20mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="a4-landscape"
        page-width="297mm" page-height="210mm"
        margin-top="0mm" margin-right="12mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-left="12mm">
        <fo:region-body region-name="page-body" margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm"/>
        <fo:region-before region-name="page-header" extent="20mm" display-align="after"/>
        <fo:region-after region-name="page-footer" extent="20mm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
```